# How to access method of tabs Pages declared from parent Page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Here's my scenario,

I declared 2 tabs in my navigation.ts and I wanted to access a method from ListPage.ts called destroyEvents() when navigation.ts triggers an ionViewWillLeave.

Because when Navigation.ts leave as active page, it doesn't invoke the ionViewWillLeave of ListPage.ts, where I recreate an events.subscribe on ionDidLoad in ListPage.ts, tendency it will create a lot of open listener/subscribers, so when somewhere fires an events.publish(string) lot of listener/subscribers created will be triggered.

See example code below:

navigation.ts

```
export class NavigationPage{

  @ViewChild('tabOpt') tabOpt: Tabs;

  cmsPage;
  listpage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.cmsPage = CMSPage;
    this.listpage = ListPage;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NavigationPage');
  }

  ionViewWillLeave(){
   this.listpage.destroyEvents(); // something like this
  }

  tabSelected(tab: Tab){
    //
  }
}
```

so in Listpage my code are

```
export class ListPage{

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ListPage');
      }

      destroyEvents(){
        this.events.unsubscribe("user:deleted", someFunction);
      } 

      someFunction(){
         // doing something
      }
    }
```